Почему значение промиса передается аргументом, но не возвращается даже через .then?
Почему значение промиса передается аргументом в функцию, но не возвращается?
Пример:
async function loadData(url) { 
    let f = await fetch(url);
    
    if (!f.ok) {
        alert('получить файл не удалось');
    } else {
        let json = await f.json();
        
        f(json); // можно передать значение промиса аргументом в функцию, четко

        return json; // возвращает промис, а не значение
    }   
}

Пробовал вернуть так:
promis.then((value)=> {
    return value; // не возвращает  
});

Или так (как в схожих вопросах здесь):
let json = await f.json();
let p = json.then((value)=> {
    return value; // не возвращает
});
return p; // не возвращает значение

Подробный код:
class Ajax {
    result(url) {
        let p = this.load(url);
        p.then((value)=> {
            return value; // не возвращает  
        });
    }

    async load(url) {   
        try {
            let f = await fetch(url);       
        
            if(!f.ok) {
                throw new SyntaxError("Файл отсутствует"); // (*)
            }
        
            let json = await f.json();
        
            if(Object.keys(json.result).length ==0) {
                throw new SyntaxError("Данные отсутствуют : выборка пустого запроса"); // (*)
            }
        
            return json;
        } catch(er) {
            alert(`Ошибка : ${er}`); // TypeError: failed to fetch
        }
    }
}

let ajax = new Ajax;

alert(ajax.result('file.php')); // undefended

result(url) {
    let p = this.load(url);
    
    p.then((value)=> {
        f(value) // передаем аругмент
    });
    //alert(v);
            
}

function f(value) {
    return value; // undefended
}


Асинхронные функции всегда возвращают промис, а последний пример кода можно сократить до this.load(url).then(f)

кстати в условиях класса все равно возвращает промис. Только если вызвать функцию за пределами класса

сейчас проверил. Функция f(value) {return value} не возвращает значение. возвращает undefended

Возвращает куда?

Возвращает в переменную, откуда был вызов функции обработчика промиса.
т.е. я могу обработать промис так
promis.then((value)=> {alert(value) // промис )}
а я хочу сделать так
promis.then((value)=> {return value // undefended)}
То есть чтобы каждый раз не выписывать .then (сделать что-то со значением внутри функции), а вызвать функцию обработчик, получить значение "на лету", типо let data = ajax.result('file.php');, и потом использовать  data.result[0], data,result[1], и тд.

Значение, возвращённое из функции внутри promise.then, будет передано в промис, который создаётся функцией promise.then - а значит, чтобы увидеть этот return value, вы должны сделать что-то вроде promis.then((value)=> {return value}).then((value)=>alert(value)) - только непонятно зачем так делать

Нужно что-то примерно такого вида
function f() {  promis.then((value)=> {return value}).then((value)=>return (value))  }
let data=  f(); data.result[0] // будет работать?
Типо чтоб вызвать функцию и получить сразу значение, без прописывания then каждый раз

Конечно не будет потому что асинхронщина, но вы всегда можете поместить data.result[0] внутрь promis.then
